# Why I am not getting Access Token and other attributes in Json Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was just going through with the JWT authentication and tried to create it in my test project, I could see it is generating the response when I am going by step while debugging but in my Json response I am getting some different output.

Not sure what I missed.

My Sample code below

Return Attributes

```
   public class UserWithToken : User
   {
     public string Access_Token { get; set; }
     public string Refresh_Token { get; set; }

    public UserWithToken(User user)
    {
        this.UserId = user.UserId;
        this.EmailId = user.EmailId;
        this.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        this.MiddleName = user.MiddleName;
        this.LastName = user.LastName;
    }
}
```

and here is my web API

```
     [HttpGet]
     [AllowAnonymous]
    public UserWithToken AuthenticateUser(string email, string pwd)
    {
        //First Validate the User
        User appUser = new User();
        TokenManager tokenManager = new TokenManager();
        appUser = appUser.GetUserDetail(email, pwd);
        if (appUser != null)
        {
            UserWithToken userToken = new UserWithToken(appUser);
            string JsonToken = tokenManager.GenerateToken(appUser);
            userToken.Access_Token = JsonToken;
            userToken.Refresh_Token = "";
            return userToken;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

but I could see it is generating token and while debugging I could see but while returning in it is different. I am using Postman to debug

{
"$id": "1",
"UserId": 1,
"EmailId": "abc@gmail.com",
"FirstName": "Mohan",
"MiddleName": "",
"LastName": "Chandra",
"EntityKey": null
}

what is $id I don't know and why it is not showing access_token and refresh_token attributes.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code to see the values?

Comment: Yes, Getting token and when I see in quick watch it is showing access_token but at last in response in Postman it is not showing.

it is showing here below line while debugging

           string JsonToken = tokenManager.GenerateToken(appUser);
            userToken.Access_Token = JsonToken;

Comment: Maybe you use json ignore or something like this on your model or DTO objects.

Comment: What is the `User` class?